# Spring Data JPA, getting duplicate constraint with Many to one relationship on owning entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called Incident, it has a field called `reporter` that references the UserEntity class.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer id;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime created;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime updated;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String hashedPassword;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserJobTypeEntity jobType;

    private String team;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 1000000)
    private byte[] profilePicture;
}
```

This is a unidirectional relationship with **Many to One** cardinality.

```java
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity reporter;
```

In my repository's upsert method I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6"
> Detail: Key (username)=(admin) already exists.

The logic for the upsert method is below:

```java
    public Incident upsert(Incident incident) {
        if (Objects.isNull(incident)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incident cannot be null when upserting");
        }

        if (!Objects.isNull(incident.id())) {
            var result = incidentDao.findById(incident.id());

            if (result.isPresent()) {
                var existingEntity = result.get();
                mapper.update(existingEntity, mapper.toEntity(incident));
                return mapper.fromEntity(incidentDao.save(existingEntity));
            }
        }
        var entityToSave = mapper.toEntity(incident);
        return mapper.fromEntity(incidentDao.save(entityToSave));
    }
```

In the debugger I can see the `reporter` property is set, after it has been mapped

[image]

I am not sure why it is trying to create a new user, is it an issue with Mapstruct transforming my domain models to entities? Or is it equals hash code issue when trying to persist?

Note- I am using Lombok carefully by explicitly only including specific fields in Equals and Hashcode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure about this line: @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER).
This relation shows many incidents can belong to one userEntity but you are saving CascadeType.ALL. which means, whenever an incident is deleted, its related userEntity will also be removed. which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Is see UserEntity in a debugger have version set to null. Spring may consider it as new record.